# React-native Expo App crashes with no errors

Tags: android, react-native, expo

After building the apk and installing it on the emulator for testing, the app crashes with no errors.
Tried some solutions but none of them seemed to work.
The project runs smoothly on expo start, but once installed on a real device, it crashes.
Checked the same issues on Stackoverflow and Github, but none of them seemed to solve my problem.

Package.json

```
  {
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "8.2.0",
    "expo": "^45.0.0",
    "expo-asset": "~8.5.0",
    "expo-font": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.2.2",
    "expo-network": "~4.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.13.3",
    "firebase": "^9.9.0",
    "map-nearest-location": "^1.1.4",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-beautiful-timeline": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.2.1",
    "react-native-link": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.30.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.11.1",
    "react-native-timeline-flatlist": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~9.1.0",
    "eslint": "^8.10.0",
    "jest-expo": "^45.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "demoapp",
    "slug": "demoapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.demo.demoapp",
      "versionCode": 1
    }
  }
}
```

App.json

```
import React, {useCallback, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {Platform, StatusBar, StyleSheet, View, LogBox} from 'react-native';
import {AppLoading} from 'expo';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator';
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import store from './modules';

export default function App() {
  const [appIsReady, setAppIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Ignore log notification by message:
    LogBox.ignoreLogs(['Warning: ...']);

    // Ignore all log notifications:
    LogBox.ignoreAllLogs();

    async function hideLoading() {
      return await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }

    async function prepare() {
      try {
        await SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();
        // Pre-load fonts, make any API calls you need to do here
        await Font.loadAsync({
          'open-sans': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
          'open-sans-bold': require('./assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf'),
        }).then(async () => {
          await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)).then(() => {
            setAppIsReady(true);
          });
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.warn(e);
      } finally {
        setAppIsReady(true);
      }
    }

    const result = prepare();
    result.then(() => {
      const isHide = hideLoading();
      isHide.then(() => {
        setAppIsReady(true);
      });
    });
  });

  if (!appIsReady) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppNavigator />
    </Provider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
});
```

Comment: try running without splash parameter in app.json

Comment: I'll try it out, and keep you updated

Comment: It didn't work, I'll check the other sections of the app and update my answer, it might help other people.

Answer (score 0):

After digging a bit more deeper, it seemed that this package https://oblador.github.io/react-native-vector-icons/ is buggy on real devices, after removing it, the apk was installed and worked well. I'll need to find another alternative and change it in the whole app, thank you.